# How can I traverse/iterate an STL map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, traversal, stdmap

I want to traverse an STL map. I don't want to use its key. I don't care about the ordering, I just look for a way to access all elements it contains. How can I do this?

Comment: refer to: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, you can traverse a Standard Library `map`.  This is the basic method used to traverse a `map`, and serves as guidance to traverse any Standard Library collection:

### C++03/C++11:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef map<int,string> MyMap;
    MyMap my_map;
    // ... magic

    for( MyMap::const_iterator it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it )
    {
      int key = it->first;
      string value = it->second;
    }
}
```

If you need to modify the elements:

- Use `iterator` rather than `const_iterator`.
- Instead of copying the values out of the iterator, get a reference and modify the values through that.

  for( MyMap::iterator it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it )
  {
    int key = it->first;
    string& value = it->second;
    if( value == "foo" )
      value = "bar";
  }

This is how you typically traverse Standard Library containers by hand.  The big difference is that for a `map` the type of `*it` is a `pair` rather than the element itself

### C++11

If you have the benefit of a C++11 compiler (for example, latest GCC with `--std=c++11` or MSVC), then you have other options as well.

First you can make use of the `auto` keyword to get rid of all that nasty verbosity:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,string> my_map;
    // ... magic

    for( auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it )
    {
      int key = it->first;
      string& value = it->second;
    }
}
```

Second, you can also employ lambdas.  In conjunction with `decltype`, this might result in cleaner code (though with tradeoffs):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,string> my_map;
    // ... magic

    for_each(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), [](decltype(*my_map.begin()) val)
    {
        string& value = val.second;
        int key = val.first;
    });
}
```

C++11 also instroduces the concept of a range-bases `for` loop, which you may recognize as similar to other languages.  However, some compilers do not fully support this yet -- notably, MSVC.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,string> my_map;
    // ... magic

    for(auto val : my_map )
    {
        string& value = val.second;
        int key = val.first;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the latest version of C++ standard you can replace the lengthy iterator decelerations with the auto keyword.

Comment: @RA: Or even better, a range based for loop. g++ 4.6.0 already supports this.

Comment: @RA: strictly speaking, in the latest *proposal* for the next version of the C++ standard, you can do that thing you said.

Comment: @John: I think you can use `auto & val` in your range-based for statement. We'll reach a proper type-inferred language some day...

Comment: @Steve:  Edited.  I'll verify once i get G++ installed.  Until then I'm trusting you!

Comment: @John: I'm pretty sure just by looking at the definition of range-based for loop that `auto` is OK. My doubt about `auto &` is that `auto` does a somewhat fiddly thing equivalent to template argument deduction, so I may have missed something. I don't have a good enough compiler to test either.

Comment: You keep copying the value out of the iterator. You should use a references as this then allows manipulation of the data within the map. `string&  value = val.second;` I think any (average) user manipulating the value would expect the internal representation of the map to change.

Comment: As this is now a [tag:C++-faq] answer, perhaps it can be cleaned up so that it is neater.

Answer (score 11):

As with any STL container, the `begin()` and `end()` methods return iterators that you can use to iterate over the map. Dereferencing a map iterator yields a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

Comment: This is wrong, not all STL container iterators yield std::pair.  There is no need for a pair in vector or list for example.

Comment: @EddieV223 fair enough, I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 9):

### C++17

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) you can use [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) together with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) for iterating over a map. The resulting code, e.g. for printing all elements of a map, is short and well readable:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m{ {3, "a"}, {5, "b"}, {9, "c"} };

for (const auto &[k, v] : m)
    std::cout << "m[" << k << "] = " << v << std::endl;
```

Output:

> m[3] = a
>   m[5] = b
>   m[9] = c

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ab008dc60321c10)

Answer (score 5):

You can traverse [STL map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) in the same way as any other STL container: using iterators, e.g.

```
for (std::map<key, value>::const_iterator
     i = myMap.begin(), end = myMap.end(); i != end; ++i)
{
    // *i is a key-value pair
}
```

Comment: I do wonder: in generally, does a compiler automatically lifts the `myMap.end()` outside of the loop ? Lifting invariants is a common optimization but I do wonder if it gets detected, I suppose it could with the implementation being inlined, but I don't *know*. Thoughts ?

Comment: @Matthieu: main thought is that `myMap.end()` is almost certainly a trivial operation. Barely worth lifting, especially considering that iterating a map isn't a very cache-friendly operation.

Comment: @Matthieu: after some header-diving: in the GNU implementation, an iterator holds a pointer to a node, and the "end node" of a map is embedded in the object. So I think that assuming several layers of calls can be inlined, constructing and returning an end iterator is basically a pointer copy, and if you're lucky `i != myMap.end()` could just be a compare of the address stored in `i`, with `myMap+offset`. I haven't disassembled any code to check, though.

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` with `auto` for C++11 and above usage

```
map<int,int> map_variable; //you can use any data type for keys, as well as value

for(auto &x:map_variable)
{ 
    cout<<x.first ;// gives the key
    cout<<x.second; //gives the value
}
```

The newer format of `for` using `auto` was introduced in C++11

To give it functionality like some higher level languages like python

Where there was already an implementation of such type of iteration

P.S. : map variable keeps values sorted, so when iterating you will get keys in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate map by using auto iterator.

### Code Snippet:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
      ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
      map<string, int> mp;

      mp["a"]=500;
      mp["b"]=200;
      mp["d"]=300;
      mp["c"]=400;

      for(auto it=mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++)
      {
         cout<<it->first <<" : "<<it->second<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
}
```