# Search for specific value in std::map

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Checking value exist in a std::map - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535317/checking-value-exist-in-a-stdmap-c)
>   [How to traverse a stl map/vector/list/etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207346/how-to-traverse-a-stl-map-vector-list-etc)

Hello,

Is it possible to search for specific value in std::map, not knowing the key? I know I could iterate over whole map, and compare values, but it is possible to do using a function from std algorithms?

Comment: For `std::map`, you'll have to iterate. Otherwise, use `boost::bimap` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535317/checking-value-exist-in-a-stdmap-c

Comment: This link shows you how to traverse a map ^^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this help? [STL find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

You need to have some sort of predicate, either a function pointer or an object with `operator()` implemented. Said predicate should take just one parameter.

Answer (score 15):

Well, you could use `std::find_if` :

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map<int, std::string> my_map;

    my_map m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(0, "zero"));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1, "one"));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2, "two"));

    const std::string s("one");
    const my_map::const_iterator it = std::find_if(
        m.begin(), m.end(), boost::bind(&my_map::value_type::second, _1) == s
    );
}
```

But that's just slightly better than a hand-crafted loop : it's still `O(n)`.

Comment: Great idea with bind!

Comment: I needed some time to understand the usage of boost::bind. Here are some pointers if anyone needs them: [Binding Member Variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/bind/binding_member_variables.html) and [Overloaded Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.overloaded_operators_new_in_boos)

Answer (score 8):

You could use [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) if you want to index on values as well as keys.  Without this or similar, this will have to be done by brute force (=> scan the `map` by hand).

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps
>   library for C++. With Boost.Bimap you
>   can create associative containers in
>   which both types can be used as key.

Comment: +1. Also, you may use two opposed STL maps, if it is not permissible to use Boost in your code.

Comment: @Stas - true, but this makes for more work - my usual response to people who are 'not allowed to use Boost' is to download the headers anyway and abstract out the code you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are (awkward) ways to do this using standard functions (e.g., [`std::find_if`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_if.html)), but these still involve iterating over the whole map. [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) will provide efficient indexing in both directions, and you can go even further with [Boost.Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).